# How to identify React component tags after build in a CRA app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I would like to create and use this component in React with ES6:

```
<Menu>
  <MenuHeader>Hi</MenuHeader>
  <MenuItem>Hello</MenuItem>
  <MenuFooter>End</MenuFooter>
</Menu>
```

I've defined a component to handle this structure:

```
export class Menu extends React.Component {

  render() {
     return (
     <div ...>
        <div ...>
           {HOW TO SELECT HEADER?}
        </div>
        <div ...>
           {HOW TO SELECT ITEM?}
        </div>
        <div ...>
           {HOW TO SELECT FOOTER?}
        </div>
     </div>
  )}
```

}

It's okay to iterate over children and select by `type.name` while running on the dev server without transpilation:

```
{ React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>  { return child.props.type === 'MenuItem' ? <>{ child }</> : '' } ) }
```

But it **does not work after building** it (cause of uglify/minify process).

For example, Semantic UI React handles it well - but it uses interfaces and written in TypeScript so I cannot use it as reference.

And one more thing (ah Steve:): I do **not** want to use `npm eject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally done by allowing the compound components inside them to render their own children and `Menu` would just render the `children` it gets, hence maintaining the order.

You might want to share the state of things happening between the Header, Body and Footer, so we add a ContextProvider to the Menu component, so they can all share common state.

```js
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { createContext } = React;

function MenuHeader({ children }) {
  return (
    <header className="menu-header">
      {children}
    </header>
  )
}

function MenuBody({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="menu-body">
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const MenuContext = createContext();
Menu.Header = MenuHeader;
Menu.Body = MenuBody;

function Menu({ children }) {
  return (
    <MenuContext.Provider value={null}>
      <div className="menu-wrapper">
        {children}
      </div>
    </MenuContext.Provider>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Header>Menu Header</Menu.Header>
      <Menu.Body>Menu Body</Menu.Body>
    </Menu>
  );
}

render(<App />, rootEl);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Another common technique used by Frameworks like Ant.Design is to map over the children and add common props to them (although context would be the better solution in my opinion)

Comment: Wov, that's more than nice, I'll test it and I will be back